# How to show loading indicator when scrolled to end of the list in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, lazy-loading

I am loading the data from the server using future and displaying the data in list view by using listview builder and adding the new list when we scroll to the end of the list but I am unable to show loading indicator while the new list of items are being loaded. I have attached my code below. I have tried the package [loadmore](https://pub.dev/packages/loadmore) but no luck.

Main.dart

```
class Herbs extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  Herbs(this.title);

  @override
  _HerbsState createState() => new _HerbsState();
}

class _HerbsState extends State<Herbs> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  var data;
  var cname;
  String gcm = '';
  List pages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPost(gcm);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        print('Page reached end of page');
        setState(() {
          Text('Loading');
        });
        fetchPost(gcm);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    cname = widget.title;
    var hgt = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65;
    var wid = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.58;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.2, 0.3),
          child: Text(
            cname,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Herbslist>(
          future: fetchPost(gcm),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Scrollbar(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: pages == null ? 0 : pages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    gcm = snapshot.data.herbslistContinue.gcmcontinue;
                    var img = pages[index].thumbnail.source;
                    return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Detailpage(
                                  pages[index].title,
                                ),
                              ));
                        },
                        child: Card(
                            child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            CachedNetworkImage(
                              placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                                'images/image.png',
                                height: hgt,
                                width: wid,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                              imageUrl: img,
                              height: hgt,
                              width: wid,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text(pages[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                            )
                          ],
                        )));
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Herbslist> fetchPost(gcm) async {
    String url =
        'https://eample.org/api.php?action=query&gcmtitle=Category:$cname&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=200&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=$gcm';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = Herbslist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      pages.addAll(data.query.pages.values);
      return data;
    } else {
      throw (e) {
        print("Exception thrown: $e");
        Exception(e);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following is the way which worked for me(Cases maybe different for others)

```
class _HerbsState extends State<Herbs> {
  bool _loading = false;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPost(gcm);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        print('Page reached end of page');
        setState(() {});
        fetchPost(gcm);
      }
    });
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: pages == null ? 0 : pages.length + 1, //add +1 here
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (index == pages.length) {
                _loading =
                    true; // declare the boolean and return loading indicator
                return Center(
                    child: Container(
                  child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ));
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the `Stack` widget and overlapping the `CircularProgressIndicator` with the `ListView`. Check the code below for a simplified example:

```
class LoadingOnScroll60619794 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingOnScroll60619794State createState() => _LoadingOnScroll60619794State();
}

class _LoadingOnScroll60619794State extends State<LoadingOnScroll60619794> {
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: runLoading
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('item 1'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          _loading
            ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
            : SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0,)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void runLoading(){
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), (){
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

---

If you modify your code to change the _loading variable whenever your are fetching the data, you will get the same effect. Like the example below:

```
Future<Herbslist> fetchPost(gcm) async {
  setState(() {
    _loading = true;
  });
  String url =
    'https://eample.org/api.php?action=query&gcmtitle=Category:$cname&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=200&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=$gcm';
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    data = Herbslist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    pages.addAll(data.query.pages.values);
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
    return data;
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
    throw (e) {
      print("Exception thrown: $e");
      Exception(e);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I did changes as you said but, that circular indicator showing at center and keeps loading the all the lists. I want to add the list when we scroll to the end of the list and show the indicator at the time when the list is being fetched.

Comment: But that's exactly what the last piece of code is doing. When you start fetching _loading becomes true, and the CircularProgressIndicator shows. When it's done, _loading becomes false and the CircularProgressIndicator is replaced and hidden.

Comment: What I mean is without scrolling to the end of list its fetching the data. I dont want to fetch without scrolling to the end of list.